# Tikz-Feynman manual placement vertex style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I'm drawing a Feynman diagram using Tikz-Feynman's manual placement:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex [label=left:\(x_1\)] (a) at (0,0);
\vertex (b) at (1,-1);
\vertex (c) at (2,-2);
\vertex (d) at (3,-3);
\vertex [label=right:\(x_2\)] (e) at (6,0);
\vertex [label=right:\(x_4\)] (g) at (6,-6);
\vertex [label=left:\(x_3\)] (f) at (0,-6);

\diagram*{
(a)  -- (b) -- [half left] (c) -- [half left] (b),
(c) -- (d) -- (e),
(f) -- (d) -- (g) 
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result of which is:

[image]

I would like each endpoint vertex (at the x's) to be a small black dot, but I can't figure out how to do so. I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312087/vertex-style-in-tikz-feynman) question, but simply adding 'dot' to the square brackets doesn't seem to do anything. Adding `(a) [dot]` within the `\diagram` environment also doesn't have any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to an MWE which we can test as it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently there is a [bug](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/24) which causes this. The issue is solved by using `\node` instead of `\vertex`. My code now looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\node [dot,label=left:\(x_1\)] (a) at (0,0);
\vertex (b) at (1,-1);
\vertex (c) at (2,-2);
\vertex (d) at (3,-3);
\node [dot,label=right:\(x_2\)] (e) at (6,0);
\node [dot,label=right:\(x_4\)] (g) at (6,-6);
\node [dot,label=left:\(x_3\)] (f) at (0,-6);

\diagram*{
(a)  -- (b) -- [half left] (c) -- [half left] (b),
(c) -- (d) -- (e),
(f) -- (d) -- (g) 
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

the syntax at page 19 of the manual uses this syntax for dashed line

the manual --- https://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.pdf

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want each vertex to be a small black dot, not the edges to be dotted lines. I will edit the question to be clearer on this