# Vertex function in tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

How can I draw the below diagram which symbolically denotes the vertex function using tikz-feynman?

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312087/vertex-style-in-tikz-feynman?rq=1

Comment: @jsbibra Resolved, thanks!